# Почему не заливает картинку post запросом в моем софте, а постманом заливает?

Tags: api, post, youtube, base64, postman

Использую для отправки **POST** запроса для отправки картинки (превью для видоса) через API на ютуб софт "browser automation studio", но не в этом суть.

**Вопрос:**
"Как правильно передать jpg картинку в бинарном формате на ютуб post запросом?"

**Как пробовал сделать юзая постман и всё отлично получилось:**
Заливаю на ютуб картинку (ставлю превьюшку для видео) юзая постман. **И все норм залетает.** Т. к. в постмане в боди выбираю тип данных binary (см скрин ниже) и выбираю файл картинки, недаром в постмане используя именно двоичный формат картинка нормально отправляется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот что как загружаю в постмане фал в бинарном формате:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Далее пробую тоже само сделать моим софтом. Взял тот же код из постмана и засунул в мой софт.**
Вот что в моем софте в body отправляю (см скриншот ниже):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вижу в анализаторе что мой софт отправил:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что в ответе ютуба я вижу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал предварительно перевести файл jpg картинки в бинарный формат используя Node.js код и сохранил результат в [[IMAGE_BINARY]] :

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// Read the image file into a buffer
const buffer = fs.readFileSync('D:\\prev.jpg');

// Convert the buffer to a binary string
const binary_image = buffer.toString('binary');


[[IMAGE_BINARY]] = binary_image;
```

Далее отправил в виде файла в полученном бинарном формате, ведь постман именно в бинарном формате отправляет, а не в формате строки base64:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мой софт выдал ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный текст ошибки из лога моего софта:

```html
~~CUSTOM~LOG~~[-][red][94101439] [13:50:44] Поток №1 : Не удалось загрузить файл ÿØÿá Exif  II*            ÿì Ducky     d  ÿáhttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ <?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 6.0-c002 79.164352, 2020/01/30-15:50:38        "> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID="xmp.did:f88fbf6a-dc4b-404b-9c5c-e1bd1ac5d86a" xmpMM:DocumentID="xmp.did:F6A9FB31080C11EB820EAB8B57A0BC39" xmpMM:InstanceID="xmp.iid:F6A9FB30080C11EB820EAB8B57A0BC39" xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Photoshop CC 2019 (Macintosh)"> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom stRef:instanceID="xmp.iid:277787d2-e00c-8449-88df-ead9bba9dbb2" stRef:documentID="adobe:docid:photoshop:b3eecc1c-7993-fc4c-bcad-be82027261dd"/> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta> <?xpacket end="r"?>ÿî Adobe dÀ   ÿÛ  ÿÀ Ð  ÿÄ'               
                
 
% !1AQa"    ðq2¡B#
±ÁÑáRb3$ñrSÓUV²C4TÔ%5µÕ&6v¶Ö'7Ww×8X¢ÒcsDte¥FGg§·(hÂ³´u¦çx9E
fH)Ãdò£¤ÄÅÆ 
     !1AQaqð¡"±ÁÑ2áñBR#³br²Ó¢Ò3Ss$Tdt´UÂCc£45u6D¤Ô%e7   ÃãÄäE&'âVòvÿÚ   ? ã[â
«> %J4éý×·eQYs"fræjêd¬Òs.¾òÛ×2~ê'ÚkÃ!Â(µ¬ÔãÓñÓñ_Ïw>ú­2OGIÒ
Ö÷n
eß\½0%{ëÑ%ÍCöªªO]Y:Óñ¤(-í/8©öÅU /i$: MV UeçZiû0ísqÏ×FläÊÓWÎªQ /Q© ä$h|ð¿¥§ÛJ·²©o*´uÂ ÎÔ+ZMTÃinä=ôÕ÷ªW¼Ö/®îº¯U3:ÕOÃÐt!'  ãßI¤'3í5h¼ºP-DÔeUÈöª­Þ®úIÒÉ8w×yÊ¨>Qð÷s¨Á]#*/ôÄi¯K«):æ )ýò£"zûÄæ>ì°Q+Ì§®3=s)ë q)þøHè¡Ô
GúZ
|ð<BxmüÏ¶¼,«ûâ Ò
4¯DTàsÇ>Ú4ö×ºþµg@��«ÇËñ Ì¢øÏ8kÒâéøT@Þkï©!\ÍtNñÄ¥ âU+Ä$j4§á÷òËôc¦Wsùk¦áî8U+ªJ+EGQøµ_Àü´
ÃÇ½æ½õH$ê9Öª*ÒO'ÞÎ¸,}¦»öæU}uG¨¥P¨ÅA>îg 
 Ë
xçïü4_üÏ´Õiubª
XÊ¢ë#/»ñ_rzÍK'çï4=g¿Ñê+ï«3ìÎ¢¸ÝqNú7þgÛ^­C«æ=ç<\
```

Comment: решил сам. все спасибо

Comment: как решил то?))